# First Generation Kindle Fire WebView <video> tag doesn't trigger the "error" callback on error

Tags: android, html, video, webview, kindle-fire

I'm embedding a `<video>` tag in a WebView for an Android application for use on the 1st generation Kindle Fire. The video doesn't play when I do `video.play()`, but my error callback doesn't get called either. I've tried setting it as an `onerror` attribute on the video itself, and also added the event to the element afterwards. [According to the spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#mediaevents), it should work, but it doesn't seem to. Any ideas?

```
video.addEventListener('error', function(err) {
  alert("error");
});
```

Comment: it looks like - in common with a couple of other Gingerbread devices - the `<video>` support in webviews isn't too robust. To play video you need hardware acceleration enabled in the manifest, but that's not available at that API level :( The annoying thing is, as you point out, error doesn't get thrown as you'd expect either

Comment: The weird thing is you'd expect there to be *some* hook at least... :)

Comment: True :( I've seen the same behavior though on my old Gingerbread based phone (now happily running Cyanogenmod... don't tell t-mobile!)